# Vehicles cannot have power locks if they do not have air conditioning

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Vehicle table.

[image]

I would like to add a check constraint to check if vehicle have air conditioning only then vehicle can have power locks.

```
alter table dbo.Vehicle 
    add constraint vehicle_aircondition_check 
        check(air_conditioning = 1);
```

How can I add IF condition here?

```
IF
    air_conditioning = 0
THEN 'power_Locks should not be 1'
```

Comment: You do know that SQL doesn't use a double equals? `==`

Comment: Please don't use images for data, code or errors. Use formatted text.

Comment: Thanks will do next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add check constraint as given below:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Vehicle
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_airconditioning 
CHECK (
  (air_conditioning = 1 and power_locks = 1) or 
  (air_conditioning = 0 and power_locks = 0) or 
  (air_conditioning = 1 and power_locks = 0)
)
```

Or additionally, one more option. thanks @Ben Thul

```sql
ALTER TABLE Vehicle
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_airconditioning 
CHECK (
  (air_conditioning = 1 and power_locks = 1) or 
  (power_locks = 0) 
)
```

if you try to enter values with wrong combination, you will get error

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 8 The INSERT statement conflicted
> with the CHECK constraint "CK_airconditioning". The conflict occurred
> in database "db1", table "dbo.vehicle".

Comment: @DaleK, you are right :) updated my answer

Comment: @DaleK, no. they want to put condition that if airconditioning = 0 then powerlocks has to be 0.

Comment: @DaleK, we need to put AND condition : air_conditioning = 1 AND power_locks = 0, it is kind of IF ELSE Logic, OP is trying to build.

Comment: Can the second and third clauses in the check constraint be combined as `(power_locks = 0)`?

Comment: @BenThul, thanks. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
CHECK (air_conditioning=1 OR power_locks=0)
```

or

```
CHECK (power_locks < air_conditioning)
```

will do one computation. If you change the fields to booleans, the first becomes `air_conditioning OR NOT power_locks`. I don't know which databases accept ordering of booleans.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one condition that you want to prevent then `not` is your friend:

```
 not ( air_conditioning = 0 and power_locks = 1 )
```